# How to extract 1st, 2nd and last words from the string using functions?

Tags: python, string, function

My program extracts only letters, but not the entire words.

```
def first_word(sentence):
    return sentence[0]
def second_word(sentence):
    return sentence[1]
def last_word(sentence):
    return sentence[-1]
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sentence = "I want to learn python"
    print(first_word(sentence))
    print(second_word(sentence))
    print(last_word(sentence))
```

The output in example above must be:

```
I
want
python
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sentence.split()` will return a list of all the words that are separated by whitespace:

```
def first_word(sentence):
    return sentence.split()[0]
def second_word(sentence):
    return sentence.split()[1]
def last_word(sentence):
    return sentence.split()[-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sentence = "I want to learn python"
    print(first_word(sentence))
    print(second_word(sentence))
    print(last_word(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split` method:

```
def first_word(sentence):
    return sentence.split()[0]  # <- HERE
def second_word(sentence):
    return sentence.split()[1]  # <- HERE
def last_word(sentence):
    return sentence.split()[-1]  # <- HERE
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sentence = "I want to learn python"
    print(first_word(sentence))
    print(second_word(sentence))
    print(last_word(sentence))
```

Output:

```
I
want
python
```